# Accessing variable form other javascript file for chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So I have a content.js file that's injected into the webpage the user is on. It gets information from this page and stores it in global variables. Now how do I display those variables in my popup.html file for my extension UI through my popup.js file??? Nothing I'm finding online is working.. I must be doing something wrong. I tried adding src = "content.js" to my popup.html before adding src = "popup.js" and popup.js still can't seem to access the variables in content.js..

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You can not access the information in your content script directly from other scripts. You will need to communicate from one to the other. You can do this by [sending messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts), or storing the value using `chrome.storage` in your content script, then reading it back in your popup.